# Need to join 4 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 tables I need to join in a query. I want all results from table 1, and then any want to join any results from table 1,2,3. I'm not sure how to write this query.

Here is my best guess:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 t1
INNER JOIN
(
 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
 FULL OUTER JOIN t3 on t3.id = t1.id
 FULL OUTER JOIN t4 on t4.id = t1.id
)
```

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join) that explains the different types of joins. From this I believe I want either a left or right join for table1, but then I am confused about the nested statement.

Comment: How are all these tables related? Knowing that will help make the query more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your question is that you want all results from table 1.  This implies a left outer join:

```
    select *
    from t1 left outer join
         t2
         on t1.id = t2.id left outer join
         t3
         on t1.id = t3.id left outer join
         t4
         on t1.id = t4.id
```

The left outer joins keep all the records on the "first" or "before" table, but not records from the second table.  Because you start with t1, all those records will be kept with only the matches to t2, and so on.

Comment: When you left outer join t3 the outer join is still relative to t1?

Comment: If I select count(*) t1 I get 594333. However if I run a count on this query I get 1125176. Seems like it is getting more rows than t1 has.

Comment: Oh wait, in a one to many multiple rows can be created for one t1.id.

Comment: @spyderman4g63 . . .exactly.  Your other tables may have more than one row for each t1.id.  Your options are to accept this, to do an aggregation, or to select one of the matching rows.